# No subclass association on Doctrine class inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I’m trying to implement this:

[image: Classes UML]

With:

### User

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SG\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", columnDefinition="ENUM('lottery')"))
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"lottery"="SG\Lottery\UserBundle\Entity\LotteryUser"})
 */
abstract class User extends Prospect
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SG\UserBundle\Entity\Subscription", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $subscriptions;
}
```

### LotteryUser

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SG\Lottery\UserBundle\Entity\LotteryUserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="lottery_users")
 */
class LotteryUser extends User
{
    // ...
}
```

### Subscription

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="subscriptions")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SG\UserBundle\Entity\SubscriptionRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"lottery"="SG\Lottery\UserBundle\Entity\Subscription"})
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="game", columnDefinition="ENUM('lottery')"))
 */
abstract class Subscription
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SG\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="subscriptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

### Lottery\Subscription

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="lottery_subscriptions")
 */
class Subscription extends \SG\UserBundle\Entity\Subscription
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SG\Lottery\GameBundle\Entity\Package")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="package")
     */
    protected $package;
}
```

But when getting the lottery users list with subscription and package tables joined:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
           ->leftJoin('u.subscriptions', 'sb')
           ->addSelect('sb')
           ->leftJoin('sb.package', 'pk')
           ->addSelect('pk');
```

It fails:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 176 near `'p LEFT JOIN u.periods'`: Error: Class `SG\UserBundle\Entity\Subscription` has no association named `package`

I don’t have any idea how to deal correctly, in the Doctrine-way, with this case. I don’t know why Doctrine doesn’t join the subclass `Lottery\Subscription` to get the `package` association whereas the subscription entry has its discriminator column to `lottery`.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Your Entity `SG\UserBundle\Entity\Subscription` doesn't have $package definition. You have to join to the `Lottery\Subscription` entity.

```
class LotteryUser extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SG\UserBundle\Entity\Lottery\Subscription", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $lotterySubscriptions;
}
```

Comment: I can’t have any reference to "lottery things" on the abstract `User` level. Furthermore, `User` does operations on its `$subscriptions` and will fail if the join is made on its `$lotterySubscriptions`. Is this the only way to implement this design?

Comment: I get `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'l10_.user' in 'on clause'`, it tries to make join the `lottery_subscriptions` table on the `user` column:

`LEFT JOIN subscriptions s4_ ON u1_.id = s4_.user 
LEFT JOIN lottery_subscriptions l5_ ON s4_.id = l5_.id 
LEFT JOIN lottery_subscriptions l10_ ON l11_.id = l10_.user`

With:

`->leftJoin('u.subscriptions', 'sb')
->addSelect('sb')
->leftJoin('u.lotterySubscriptions', 'lsb')
->addSelect('lsb')
->leftJoin('lsb.package', 'p')
->addSelect('p')`

Comment: did you try this after a doctrine:schema:update and cache:clear?

Comment: Yes I did. I think the solution is simply to ask Doctrine not to join the `lottery_subscriptions` table on the `user` column. But it seems Doctrine doesn’t allow anymore to override the `ON` clause.

Comment: run ```php app/console doctrine:mapping:info``` to check if all entity are right defined